# Height-dependent filling color in 3D Data Plots

Tags: graphics, color

I would like to have the filling of my `ListPlot3D` display the same color than the one applied to the data. This question makes sense only in the case of conditional coloring of data (according to their height for example). 
Moreover, I am using the option `InterpolationOrder -> 0` and I understand what I ask is kind of tricky in case of higher orders.

Here is a minimal example

```
table = {{1, 2, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 3, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4}};
ListPlot3D[
    table, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 0,
    ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
    Filling -> Axis,
    FillingStyle -> {Opacity[1]}, Mesh -> None
    ]
```

which gives gray filling beneath the data.

My question is the following :

Is it possible to specify a dynamic color in the `FillingStyle` so that it will match the data ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If nobody comes with a much cleverer solution, this might be a way to achieve what you're looking for. However, first your data have to be reshaped.

```
newtable = {{1, 2, 1}, {3, 1, 3}, {4, 3, 4}};
BarChart3D[newtable, ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
    ViewPoint -> {3.33, -8.26, 5.36}, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", 
    Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}]
```

[image: plot1]

With some additional options:

```
BarChart3D[newtable, ChartLayout -> "Grid", ChartElementFunction -> "Cube",
    ViewPoint -> {3.33, -8.26, 5.36}, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
    Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, BarSpacing -> {None, None}]
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: One could indeed say that the use of ListPlot3D is not optimal in my case. I like your solution, especially adding  `BarSpacing -> {0, 0}`

Answer (score 10):

There is also ... `DiscretePlot3D`

With appropriate settings for the options `ExtentSize` and `ColorFunction` you get something similar to `BarChart3D`:

Two examples:

```
Row[{
  DiscretePlot3D[table[[i, j]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1., 1., .7}, ExtentSize -> Scaled[.75], 
   ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &)],
  DiscretePlot3D[table[[i, j]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1., 1., .7}, ExtentSize -> Full, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   ExtentElementFunction -> "ProfileCube"]
 }]
```

[image: discreteplot3d examples]

Answer (score 8):

You could use graphics primitives to construct your plot. For example

```
{min, max} = Through[{Min, Max}[Flatten[table]]];
Graphics3D[
 MapIndexed[{ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Rescale[#1, {min, max}]], 
    Cuboid[Append[#2, 0], Append[#2 + {1, 1}, #1]]} &, table, {2}], 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> True]
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

As usual, when something does not give away itself readily, make your own function from scratch. This topped barchart-like plotter I have built for my own purposes to visualize 5 dimensions of data: $x$ and $y$ position, $z$ height, bar color and top color. I also included the background of `BarChart3D` as `back`, but that can be omitted.

```
(* BarcChart3D background *)
vertex = {Directive[Opacity@.2, RGBColor[1/3, 1/3, 2/3]], 
   Directive[Opacity@.2, RGBColor[1/2, 1/2, 1]], 
   Directive[Opacity@.2, RGBColor[2/3, 2/3, 1]], 
   Directive[Opacity@.2, GrayLevel@1]};
back = {
   EdgeForm@GrayLevel@0.85,
   (* Bottom *)
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0.015, 0.02, 0.02}, Scaled@{0.985, 0.02, 0.02}, 
     Scaled@{0.985, 0.98, 0.02}, Scaled@{0.015, 0.98, 0.02}}, 
    VertexColors -> vertex],
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0.015, 0.02, 0.02}, Scaled@{0.985, 0.02, 0.02}, 
     Scaled@{1, 0, 0}, Scaled@{0, 0, 0}}, VertexColors -> vertex],
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0.985, 0.02, 0.02}, Scaled@{1, 0, 0}, 
     Scaled@{1, 1, 0}, Scaled@{0.985, 0.98, 0.02}}, 
    VertexColors -> vertex],
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0.015, 0.98, 0.02}, Scaled@{0.985, 0.98, 0.02}, 
     Scaled@{1, 1, 0}, Scaled@{0, 0.99, 0}}, VertexColors -> vertex],
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0.015, 0.02, 0.02}, Scaled@{0, 0, 0}, 
     Scaled@{0, 0.99, 0}, Scaled@{0.015, 0.98, 0.02}}, 
    VertexColors -> vertex],
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0, 0, 0}, Scaled@{1, 0, 0}, Scaled@{1, 1, 0}, 
     Scaled@{0, 0.99, 0}}, VertexColors -> vertex],
   (* Back *)
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0.015, 0.98, 0.02}, Scaled@{0.985, 0.98, 0.02}, 
     Scaled@{0.985, 0.98, 0.98}, Scaled@{0.015, 0.98, 0.98}}, 
    VertexColors -> vertex],
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0.015, 0.98, 0.02}, Scaled@{0.985, 0.98, 0.02}, 
     Scaled@{1, 1, 0}, Scaled@{0, 0.99, 0}}, VertexColors -> vertex],
   Polygon[{Scaled@{1, 1, 0}, Scaled@{1, 1, 1}, 
     Scaled@{0.985, 0.98, 0.98}, Scaled@{0.985, 0.98, 0.02}}, 
    VertexColors -> vertex],
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0.015, 0.98, 0.98}, Scaled@{0.985, 0.98, 0.98}, 
     Scaled@{1, 1, 1}, Scaled@{0, 1, 1}}, VertexColors -> vertex],
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0.015, 0.98, 0.02}, Scaled@{0, 0.99, 0}, 
     Scaled@{0, 1, 1}, Scaled@{0.015, 0.98, 0.98}}, 
    VertexColors -> vertex],
   Polygon[{Scaled@{0, 0.99, 0}, Scaled@{1, 1, 0}, Scaled@{1, 1, 1}, 
     Scaled@{0, 1, 1}}, VertexColors -> vertex]
   };


(* define some data of 4 dimensions: x, y, z height and top color *)
{m, n} = {10, 6};
data = Partition[Sort@Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {m*n}], n];

(* {z and top color position in data entries, horizontal and vertical gaps} *)
{z, top, hGap, vGap} = {1, 2, 0.075, 1/1000};

(* let's plot the whole thing *)
Graphics3D[
 Join[{back},
  Flatten@Table[{
     Opacity@0.5, EdgeForm@None, FaceForm@Hue@data[[x, y, z]], 
     Cuboid[{y - .5 + hGap, x - .5 + hGap, 0}, {y + .5 - hGap, 
       x + .5 - hGap, data[[x, y, z]]}],(* bar *)
     Opacity@1.0, EdgeForm@Black, FaceForm@Hue@data[[x, y, top]], 
     Cuboid[{y - .5 + hGap, x - .5 + hGap, 
       data[[x, y, 1]] + vGap}, {y + .5 - hGap, x + .5 - hGap, 
       data[[x, y, z]] + vGap}] (* top *)
     }, {x, m}, {y, n}]]
 ,
 BoxRatios -> 1, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It might need some fiddling with axes, plot ranges and similar.