# Displaying a matrix as an array of solid rectangular blocks

Tags: plotting, graphics, matrix

I would like to plot an array of numbers as a surface, with each number
the height of a square, and with the squares connected to adjacent
squares with vertical rectangles, up or down as appropriate.
So in the end the whole looks like an array of solid rectangular blocks,
with square cross-sections.

Is there a way to accomplish this with `ListPlot3D`?
I can get the squares floating in space, but I don't see how to easily
connect with vertical rectangles.

```
m={{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7}, {3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 
  8, 5, 6}, {4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5}, {5, 7, 6, 8, 1, 3, 2, 4}, {6, 8,
   5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 3}, {7, 5, 8, 6, 3, 1, 4, 2}, {8, 6, 7, 5, 4, 2, 3, 
  1}};
ListPlot3D[mtab, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

---

[image: GroupTable]

---

Comment: E.g. `ListPlot3D[m, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> Orange]`. I guess  this has been already asked.

Comment: @Artes: Fantastic! Thanks so much!

Comment: related Q/A: [Height-dependent filling color in 3D plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3333/125)

Comment: @Artes: Nice, I was going to say you could add the option `Exclusions -> None`, but then I found out that `Exclusions` is not a valid option for `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: @Artes Are you going to post that as an answer or do you think this should be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guesss there one could  answer who is searching for reputation. I try to avoid answering plotting tag since I believe everything  regarding this topic has been answered so far somewhere on this site. I don't neccesarily  claim this is a duplicate so I think one can answer this question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Feel free to close it as duplicate.